# Auto capture Date & Time when status is selected as YES

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am looking for someone who can help me with this issue.
i want to auto capture Date and Time when an associate select Status as "YES".
Example Cell A in a share point is Status Yes and No
Cell B is Completed Date & Time.
When an associate select Status as "YES" automatically it should take Date and Time in B feild.
I have tried Now() function but it is changing date and time for all previously closed Items.
request you all to help me with this issue. 
Thanks.

Comment: You could try using Sharepoint designer, make a workflow that includes the LOG command, then it could log the date and time.  Or a variable might capture this for you too.  I'm no expert in this area, but someone else might post a fuller answer on how to do this.

Comment: you need to do it with workflow and set this run for new items.